# Unable to load large images into web view android

Tags: android, html, webview, rich-notifications

I think its because images are large, but, if anybody has different opinion, please, share.

So, im receiving notification like HTML, and want to present it in web view. Now, when i present notifications with smaller pictures, everything works fine. When I present notifications with bigger picture(s), text is there, but image has icon like it crashed. What can I do to make this work?

```
        mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.party_web_view);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.loadData( mContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did was this:

```
mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.party_web_view);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            mWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

and then, when loading some content,

```
 mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadData(mContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps..